# Body for searching anywhere

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, match, field

In Elasticsearch, it is easy to perform the following search request, for example via the browser:

```
<protocol>://<address>:<port>/<index>/_search?q="search term"
```

This must use some kind of default combination of matching over various index fields.

The usual examples one can find for searching by search body address search in **specific fields**.

What is the correct search body for the above type of URL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `q=...` is actually equivalent to a [`query_string`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) search.

So `.../index/_search?q="search term"` would be equivalent to

```
GET index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "search term"
    }
  }
}
```

One of the parameter of the `query_string`  query is `default_field`, which if not specified is equal to the value of the index setting called `index.query.default_field`, which has a default value of `*` (i.e. all fields)

If you want to restrict the search to a specific field, then you can do so:

```
GET index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "search term",
      "default_field": "content"
    }
  }
}
```

And this would be equivalent to `.../index/_search?q=content:"search term"`

Comment: Thanks! I am sure this is somewhere hidden in the docs, but perhaps some other people agree with me that the ES docs are one huge mess ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question then?

Comment: The first line of my answer has a link to the actual documentation related to this but it doesn't show really well due to SO styling.

Comment: I googled "Elasticsearch search anywhere", but this only directs to full-text query...

Comment: Well, Google is right, full-text queries is exactly where you'll find the `query_string` one: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/full-text-queries.html

Comment: And if you look at the Search API documentation, you'll find easily the description of how the `q` parameter works: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html#search-api-query-params-q, but agreed, it could link to the `query_string` query directly